# Route if a given string is matched in the url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple `join=yes` that can be passed by GET to any of my app urls. When detected it simply redirects to a specific `JoinsController` controller. Otherwise it just keep the regular flow.

My questions is how could I match a specific pattern like `join=yes` in order to redirect it to the `JoinsController`?

Comment: I'm guessing a few things here. You are using rails? If so, join is a parameter? If so, have you tried doing `redirect_to your_controller_acount_path and return if params[:join] == "yes"`

Comment: Yes, I'm using Rails. Is there any way to handle this at a routes level? Since this apply to all application across multiple controllers, I'm wondering If there's a way to handle it globally.

Comment: In that case do a before_filter on your ApplicationController and define a method that will redirect to your JoinsController on that condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting some kind of constraint into your `routes.rb`. e.g.:

```
constraints(:join => "true") do
  match '/*path', :to => redirect(url)
end
```

More on constrains in [Rails API - ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Scoping](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Scoping.html#method-i-constraints)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the redirect to happen across all other controllers you could do it many ways. The way I would do it is something like this:

**application_controller.rb**

```
def ApplicationController<ActionController::Base
  before_filter :needs_join_controller

  def needs_join
    redirect_to your_controller_action_path and return if params[:join] == "yes"
  end
end
```

Then your joins controller would need to skip this before filter to avoid multiple redirects

**joins_controller.rb**

```
def JoinsController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :needs_join_controller

end
```